# How to connect UiPath Studio with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, tfs, rpa, uipath-studio

I need to connect UiPath Studio with Azure DevOps, but I got an error TF10175, I searched the internet but I did not find an answer to move forward with my project.
I enclose the description of the error.
In advance thanks a lot for your response.

```
19.9.2+Branch.master.Sha.0928919eb1def274fdabeb0849d03a125c50fe6a

TF10175: The Desarrollo RPA team project does not exist.


Error: UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.TfsOperationException: TF10175: The Desarrollo RPA team project does not exist.

   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.Session.TfsSession.ThreadSafeExecute[TResult](Func`2 action, OperationRecord& operationRecordRecord)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.Session.TfsSession.<>c__DisplayClass23_1`1.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0(CancellationToken _)
   en UiPath.Shared.ProducerConsumerPair.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<StartNew>b__0()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.Session.TfsSession.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__23`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.Session.TfsSession.<ExecuteAndMonitorAffectedItemsAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.TfsSourceControl.<AddItemAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.TfsSourceControl.<AddUnversionedFilesAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Tfs.TfsSourceControl.<CheckInAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckInUiService`2.<ExecuteCheckIn>d__21.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckInUiService`2.<CheckInSelectedChanges>d__20.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckInUiService`2.<CheckInCommandExecute>d__18.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.CentralRepositoryCheckInUiService`1.<CheckInCommandExecute>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.SourceControl.Shared.Services.UI.BaseCheckInUiService`2.<<get_CheckInCommand>b__14_0>d.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en UiPath.Studio.Shared.MVVM.Commands.TaskCommand`3.<Execute>d__32.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   en System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler), HResult -2146233088
```

Comment: Hi Nenton, please format your post properly

Answer (score 2):

I also use UiPath and Azure DevOps. So this is how I connected both of them:

1. First of all I recommend to use **TortoiseGit** over UiPath Git because the Git Setup of UiPath is just properly working on a single repo. But If you like to use multiple Processes in the Repo UiPath Git is kind of buggy still.
2. So install [**TortoiseGit**](https://tortoisegit.org/) .
3. Now go to your [**project**](https://dev.azure.com/).
4. Note the **credentials** and save them (depends on how you want to auth later on).
5. Go to your **Azure folder** on your PC or create a New one. I like to add a new one on C:\user\myname\Git\newrepo
6. In that folder do a rightclick. And select Git Clone. Here give in the URL of the Azure. Something like this `https://yourspace@dev.azure.com/yourpoject/reponame/_git/yourfolder` and click on **Clone**.
7. Now you should get a Popup of Microsoft Login. Here enter your Microsoft Credentials. If not you need to enter the Azure **Credentials** from #4. This is for authing you as the owner of the repo.
8. Now Git is downloading all stuff and you are ready. Now you can add files or edit them.
9. After that the easiest way is to rightclick the folder and select **Git Commit**. But UiPath is now also available. Therefore go UiPath and select Git and the Repo folder. Now UiPath is also connected and ready to be used.

Comment: Thanks for this information. You only use git repo from azure or you also use the piplene to create nugetpackages an deploy them to orchestrators?

Comment: Hey Stephu what do mean with Pipeline? You mean Deploy/Publish project? This has nothing to do with Git if you mean this. When you Publish a process it is usually connected with your Orchestrator and not anywhere saved locally. So you can change the version in Orchestrator. In Git you will always have only the latest version. But maybe I got you wrong? Better tell me what your purpose is =)

Comment: Hey kwoxer. Git is only the source repository. I mean "continouse integratoin". In the case I commit I like that a build piple builds a nuget package and uploads this to a test orchestrator. In the case I approve this package in azure the piple uploads the packages to production orchestrator.

Comment: Good point tho, but maybe we should wait for a comment of @Nenton. It's not clear what he really needs.